# Wait for an async callback to finish before completing separate function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Apologies if this is a repeat, but all I can find is help to let the function finish or unrelated languages, not what to do after.  Anyway...

So, I have two other-wise unrelated functions.  One calls the Namey API, which returns a random name in a callback, and I use that to update an element.  This is my randomizePANameListeners function.

My second function takes the first name and last name from those two elements and uses them to create a random username.  This is my randomizeAppNameListeners.

```
randomizePANameButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

              //  Check the gender of the PA
            var isChecked = document.getElementById("gender56").checked;

              //  Use a self-invoking function to make sure the names are
              //  updated correctly
            (function() {
              if (isChecked === true) {
                namey.get({ type: 'male', with_surname: 'false', frequency: 'all', callback: function(n) { document.getElementById("fName").value = n }});
              } else {
                namey.get({ type: 'female', with_surname: 'false', frequency: 'all', callback: function(n) { document.getElementById("fName").value = n }});
              }

                //  Set the surname as well
              namey.get({ type: 'surname', with_surname: 'false', frequency: 'all', callback: function(n) { document.getElementById("lName").value = n }});
            })()
```

And, attached to a second button's event listener:

```
    var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value.substring(0, 3);
    var lName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
    var randomDigits = (Math.random() * (100 - 10) + 10).toFixed(0);

    return fName + lName + ".UAT" + randomDigits;
```

Now, I have one button to make everything easier by tying all of these event listeners together.  My easy button does everything for me, but when it calls these two it takes the current values in the elements to make the random name and then creates a new application name, it doesn't take the new PA name.

So, using vanilla JavaScript, how do I wait for the first function to complete before finishing the second?  I would prefer not to create an unneeded global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In native javascript you can use callbacks in your own functions

```
var myFunction = function(complete) {
  /* Do things here first */
  complete();
}
myFunction(function(){
  /* Do Something else here after the first has completed */
});
```

Comment: Your comment is the closest to helping me. I would've liked to have kept the scope of these two more separate, but I ended up putting the function call to create the app name inside the callback for the surname.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it with promises - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

This should work :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use promises which works for exactly in your scenario and if you are using jquery, you can use deferred.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/